# How to show/hide div with jQuery while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a "floating toolbar" which by default is hidden. After a certain amount of scrolling down, it will be shown. And eventually when user scrolls up, nearing the top of the screen, the toolbar will be hidden again. And so on.

Here's [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/d5L2rohv/14/) (modified from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp)).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myHeader").hide();
});

window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};
window.onload = function() {
  $('.myHeader').hide()
};


var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}

/*
$(window).scroll(function(){
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0){
  $('.top-container').show(); 
 }
 else {
  $('.top-container').hide();
 }
}*/


$('window').scrollDown(function() {
  $('.myHeader').hide()
});
$('window').scrollUp(function() {
  $('.myHeader').show()
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="top-container">
    <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
    <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <button type="button">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button">Button 2</button>
    <button type="button">Button 3</button>
    <button type="button">Button 4</button>
    <button type="button">Button 5</button>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
    <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
    <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

The div is still visible. What goes wrong here?

Comment: What is `scrollDown` and `scrollUp`? What says the console? Any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your question, and also include some scenarios, according to which you want the code to run.

Comment: @Code_Ninja. OK. When the page is loaded, the div containing the buttons (the toolbar) is hidden. Then eventually the user scrolls down. After a certain amount of scrolling down, then the toolbar is shown. The toolbar is still shown after the user reach the bottom of the screen. Eventually, the user wants to scroll up. Eventually when reaching near top of the screen. the toolbar is hidden again. And so forth.

Comment: by toolbar, you mean the header in which buttons are displayed? an when you go to the top of the page, do you want to hide that header?

Answer (score 3):

I have made changes to your code. You were using `$('.myHeader')` to get the element. You didn't had this class myHeader but you had id `myHeader`. So use `$('#myHeader')`. Secondly I have added `show()` and `hide()` method where you were adding class sticky to the element.
This will work for you now

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myHeader").hide();
});

window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
window.onload = function() {$('#myHeader').hide()};


var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
    $(header).show();
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
    $(header).hide();
  }
}

/*
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0){
        $('.top-container').show(); 
    }
    else {
        $('.top-container').hide();
    }
}*/


$('window').scrollDown(function(){$('#myHeader').hide()});
$('window').scrollUp(function(){ $('#myHeader').show() });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="top-container">
    <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
    <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <button type="button">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button">Button 2</button>
    <button type="button">Button 3</button>
    <button type="button">Button 4</button>
    <button type="button">Button 5</button>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
    <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
    <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```